# Statistics, exponential distribution

Tags: statistics

I got the following task:

The durability for a light bulb is following an exponential distribution with the expected value 800 hours. In a room there are 30 bulbs and all of them started to shine at the same point of time. Calculate the probability that at least 18 bulbs shine after 1000 hours.

The correct answer should be: 1-Fz((17,5-8,595)/sqrt6,13)=0,0000. How do I get there?

Comment: Atleast 18 bulbs of how many that you sampled?.

Comment: sorry. there are 30 in the sample. Check me edit

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Probability that a bulb will shine after 1000 hours $$P(T>=1000) = 1-P(T<1000)$$.  The expected value $ = 800 $ hours.  Thus $\lambda = \frac{1}{800}$.  $$P(T>=1000) = e^{-\lambda\times t} = e^{-\frac{1000}{800}} = 0.286505$$. Of 30 bulbs, you need P(X>=18).  This follows Binomial distirbution which can again be approximated by Normal with mean = $np$ and Variance =$npq$. Mean$ = 8.595$ and Variance =$6.13$.  Now $$P(X>=18) = 1-P(X<=17) = 1-P(Z<=\frac{17+.5 - 8.595}{\sqrt{6.13}}) $$The addition of 0.5 to 17 is to adjust for continuity correction.$$=1=P(Z<\frac{(17.5 - 8.5950}{\sqrt{6.13}}) = 1-P(z<=3.595) = 1-0.99983835 = 0.000162$$.  Thus the required probability  $=0.000162$

Thanks

Satish